# EditText IME action different on different devices

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard, ime

I have an `EditText` which has an IME action specified.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/passwordEditText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/prompt_password"
    android:imeActionId="@+id/login"
    android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in"
    android:imeOptions="actionGo"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:maxLines="1" />
```

But on Nexus 5(Android 5.1.1) I get IME_ACTION_UNSPECIFIED (0) and on Samsung Galaxy(Android 4.2.2) I get IME_ACTION_GO(2).

Is this due to the device or the android version? How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why but if you try to set `imeActionId` (2)IME_ACTION_GO, it works on Nexus 5(Android 5.1.1) too. I hope this solution help you.

Cheers

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/passwordEditText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/prompt_password"
    android:imeActionId="2"
    android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in"
    android:imeOptions="actionGo"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:maxLines="1" />
```

Comment: Also you want to check these links:
[link 1](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/style.html#Action)
[link 2](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:imeActionId)

Comment: got it.  android:imeActionId="2" is required.